# error: Error: Unable to resolve module `./contants/icons` from `screens/index.js

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

[Tue Apr 20 2021 11:44:30.800]  BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module `./contants/icons` from `screens/index.js`:

None of these files exist:

- screens/contants/icons(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- screens/contants/icons/index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/touseef/Downloads/NewAPP/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:163:15)
  at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (/Users/touseef/Downloads/NewAPP/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
  at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/touseef/Downloads/NewAPP/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:287:16)
  at Object.resolve (/Users/touseef/Downloads/NewAPP/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:267:42)
  at /Users/touseef/Downloads/NewAPP/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:434:31
  at Array.map ()
  at resolveDependencies (/Users/touseef/Downloads/NewAPP/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:431:18)
  at /Users/touseef/Downloads/NewAPP/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:275:33
  at Generator.next ()
  at asyncGeneratorStep (/Users/touseef/Downloads/NewAPP/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:87:24)

Comment: is this "./contants/icons" should be constants - can you verify this typo.

Comment: I have solved it by writing '../constants/icons'

Comment: sure. can you mark this as answered and upvote my comment since it's helpful.